# MinGW isn't outputting executable or object file

Tags: c, mingw

I've just started using MinGW and I'm having an issue where it isn't outputting an executable or an object file, or anything really. After fixing a few errors everything compiles fine, but no executable is being outputted. When I first installed MinGW I tested it on a simple hello world program and everything worked correctly, but I'm trying to write a basic windows application and it's not working. I've worked with gcc before, but only briefly, I don't really know anything about it.

```
C:\Users\Cole\Dev\Hello Windows\>gcc win_main.c -o win_main
```

Here's the win_main.c file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
 * Global Variables
 */
HWND g_hwnd = NULL;
HINSTANCE g_hinst = NULL;

/*
 * Forward Declarations
 */
LRESULT CALLBACK win_proc(HWND h_wnd, UINT message, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param);
HRESULT init_window(HINSTANCE h_instance, int cmd_show);

/*
 * Main entry point to the application.
 */
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE h_instance, HINSTANCE h_previnstance, LPSTR cmd_line, int cmd_show) {

    if(FAILED(init_window(h_instance, cmd_show)))
        return -1;

    MSG msg = {0};
    while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

/*
 * Register window class and create the window.
 */
HRESULT init_window(HINSTANCE h_instance, int cmd_show) {

    /* Register window class. */
    WNDCLASSEX wcx;
    wcx.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcx.style = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
    wcx.lpfnWndProc = win_proc;
    wcx.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcx.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcx.hInstance = h_instance;
    wcx.hIcon = NULL;
    wcx.hIconSm = NULL;
    wcx.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcx.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcx.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcx.lpszClassName = "BasicWindowClass";

    if(!RegisterClassEx(&wcx)) {
        printf("Failed to register window class.\n");
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    /* Create the window. */
    g_hinst = h_instance;
    RECT rc = {0, 0, 640, 480};
    AdjustWindowRect(&rc, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);
    g_hwnd = CreateWindow("BasicWindowClass", "Windows Application", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
        rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top, NULL, NULL, g_hinst, NULL);

    if(g_hwnd == NULL) {
        printf("Failed to create the window.\n");
        return E_FAIL;
    }

    ShowWindow(g_hwnd, cmd_show);

    return S_OK;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK win_proc(HWND h_wnd, UINT message, WPARAM w_param, LPARAM l_param) {

    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch(message) {
        case WM_PAINT:
            hdc = BeginPaint(h_wnd, &ps);
            EndPaint(h_wnd, &ps);
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;

        default:
            return DefWindowProc(h_wnd, message, w_param, l_param);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you want to say that after having executed `gcc win_main.c -o win_main`, there's no `win_main.exe` file in the same directory the source file lies in?

Comment: In your environment, is `gcc` a binary, or some script which might redirect critical output?

Comment: gcc is a binary file located in C:\MinGW\bin

Comment: can you compile the "hello world program" again?

Comment: Yep. I tried compiling it again to see if maybe something went wrong, but it compiles and executes without problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add -mwindows  `gcc -mwindows win_main.c -o win_main` .I guess your first program was using a 'main' function as entry point...

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. What's weird is that win_main.exe will show up briefly, but when I try to double click on it, or execute it from the command line, it just disappears and windows gives me an error about not being able to find the file win_main.exe

Comment: Could it be an anti-virus thing?

Comment: Yep it's my anti-virus. I disabled the auto-pilot mode for bitdefender and now I'm getting a virus warning when trying to execute win_main.exe.

Comment: @Cole: yes, antivirus programs interfere with programming. Disable the "autosandboxing" and whatnot, heck, exclude your whole development directory from being scanned.

Comment: I went ahead and excluded my development directory and it works now. Thanks.